# function to format regex match

Tags: java, regex, formatting

I am writing a java function with 3 parameters (input text, regex match, output formatting) to return formatted text. Here's what I got so far:

Input text sample 1:

```
6_103319_10_ContractsSummary.csv
6_103319_ContractsSummary.csv
```

regex match:

```
([0-9]*)_([0-9]*)_([0-9]*)_?ContractsSummary.csv
```

output format:

```
$1.$2.$3
```

Current result

```
6.103319.10
6.103319.
```

Desired result:

```
6.103319.10
6.103319
```

Input text sample 2:

```
Accounts-Summary-123456-20181101.csv
Accounts-Summary-123456.csv
```

regex match:

```
Accounts-Summary-([0-9]*)-?([0-9]*)?.csv
```

output format:

```
$1_$2
```

Current result

```
123456_20181101
123456_
```

Desired result:

```
123456_20181101
123456
```

The problem I have is the extra `.` or '_' returned when the 3rd regex group does not exist. It's not necessary to have to always do replacements for some characters, the output format should be fully controlled by the output format parameter.

This is my current function code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexMatch);
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputText);

if (m.find()){
    formattedText=m.replaceFirst(outputFormat);
}
```

Comment: Try [`inputText.replaceFirst("^(\\d+(?:_\\d+)*)_ContractsSummary\\.csv$", "$1").replace("_", ".")`](https://ideone.com/eq7aal).

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, but this wouldn't work, because I need to write this in a function, the . is not necessarily the pattern I want to replace the _ with

Comment: Please explain: do you mean you cannot change the code? Do you want to do everything with a mere string pattern and a string replacement? Then it is not possible because Java `replaceAll` / `replaceFirst` methods do not support conditional string replacement patterns. You will need a `Matcher#appendReplacement` method.

Comment: correct, I want to do with the string pattern and string replacement. i can change the code, so if you provide an example with Matcher.appendReplacement It might work for me

Comment: See https://ideone.com/XQG0qk

Comment: Does the first one not fail on the ideone example, @WiktorStribiżew?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this wouldn't work because you're assuming we always have a . whereas we want the user of the function to specify the output pattern which could include . or not

Comment: That is out of this question scope. You may pass the delimiter as an argument to *your* method, and then replace the hardcoded `.` with that variable. Yeah, I fixed the code now, the `_` was missing. See [the **code update**](https://ideone.com/XQG0qk).

Comment: I made another update, see [the **code update**](https://ideone.com/XQG0qk) again.

Comment: thanks, I saw it but the code should read formatting instructions from the output format parameter exclusively, so it's possible to have many matching groups and possibly no need for character substitution.

Comment: Then you are stuck forever, it is NOT possible.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what flexibility you want for the output format. Wouldn't the easiest fix for your example be to just drop the trailing dot afterwards?

```
formttedText=m.replaceFirst(outputFormat).replaceFirst("\\.$", "");
```

Comment: thank you, but I cannot know upfront what characters need to be dropped, I need to include this flexibility in the parameters passed to the function to return the formatted output

Answer (score 0):

An alternate to @Wiktors comment, if you don't want to use `regex`, you could loop through the String and append the digit, or a dot depending on if it's an underscore (and the following character is a digit).

```
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
            sb.append(s.charAt(i));
        } else if (s.charAt(i) == '_' && Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i + 1))) {
            sb.append(".");
        }
    }
```

[Online example](https://ideone.com/seeICB)

Comment: thank you, but this wouldn't work. similar comment as the one for @Wiktor: the . or _ should be part of the regex and substitution strings that are passed to the function

Comment: Ok, then is https://ideone.com/cB1ota something what you're looking for? Obviously I hardcoded in the `dropped` and `replacement` variables, but they can be read however necessary.

Comment: @steelmans1980 Or even https://ideone.com/bSs70H if you know it's only one character, and you know the replacement...

Comment: thank you, your new suggestion is still dependent on the sample format of the text. There are cases where the user of the function does not need to drop characters, hence why the function needs to be more generic. the actual use for this function is in a preprocessor, which reads filenames and outputs formatted strings as instructed by the preprocessor parameters which are 3 in total: the filename, the pattern to match, the output format